# Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host,npgsql

Tags: winforms, postgresql

```
 static string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=xxx;Database=Information;";``

 using (NpgsqlConnection pgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    // Open the PgSQL Connection.                  
                    pgsqlConnection.Open();

                    string insertCommand = "fnInsertRecord";

                    using (NpgsqlCommand pgsqlcommand = new NpgsqlCommand(insertCommand, pgsqlConnection))
                    {
                        using (NpgsqlTransaction tran = pgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            pgsqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            //pgsqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("playername", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
                            //pgsqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("age", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
                            //pgsqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("belongsto", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
                            //pgsqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("salary", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));

                            pgsqlcommand.Parameters["p_PlayerName"].Value = PlayerName;
                            pgsqlcommand.Parameters["p_Salary"].Value = Age;
                            pgsqlcommand.Parameters["p_BelongsTo"].Value = BelongsTo;
                            pgsqlcommand.Parameters["p_Age"].Value = Salary;

                            pgsqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            tran.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

the connection not opening it show the above error...any body have solution for it.

the error code is :

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I tried : 
i opened 5432 port opened through firewall
restarted computer

Comment: Check whether Postgres service is running or not

Comment: i am newbie to postgres...will u explain how to check...

Comment: Just try to open pgAdmin

Comment: check your Firewall and anti-virus .. see this -http://stackoverflow.com/a/11193685/3682599 also

Comment: my firewall 5432 is opened and no antivirus,defender also off

Comment: i will post my pg_hba config settings below

Comment: # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

Comment: Just for a test change method in pg_hba from `md5` to `trust`

Comment: 127.0.0.0/32 what it mean

Comment: `127.0.0.0/32` localhost IP address that means your postgresql server will accept connection(s) from local computer only and `0.0.0.0` will accepts connection from everywhere

Comment: static string connString = "Server=127.0.0.1/32 ;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=xxx;Database=Information;";

Comment: is it correct connection string

Comment: No, `Server=127.0.0.1` is the correct one, what's your OS ??

Comment: windows 7 ultimate 64 bit

Comment: So, `server=localhost` here(becuase OS is windows 7) localhost will be IPV6 address so you should change `server=localhost` to `server=127.0.0.1` according to your `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: so what i have to change in connection string littel bit confused

Comment: Connection string should be `static string connString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=xxx;Database=Information;";`

Comment: # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5